# How can I take a str/.txt input and make it into a list for pyton

Tags: python, list

I have a text file where the information that is formated as

Title, Author, User Rating, Reviews, Price, Publication Year, Genre(Fiction or nonfiction)

sample data form txt

```
test_data = """ 
    Girls,Hopscotch Girls,4.8,9737,7,2019,Non Fiction
    I - Alex Cross,James Patterson,4.6,1320,7,2009,Fiction
    If Animals Kissed Good Night,Ann Whitford Paul,4.8,16643,4,2019,Fiction
 """
```

They are all separated by a comma (,). I wanted to take this input and make it into a list that looks something like

```
list = {'Name': 'Girls','Author': 'Hopscotch Girls','User Rating':'4.8', 'Reviews':'9737', 'Price':'7', 'Publication Year':'2019', 'Genre':'Non Fiction'}
```

I'm trying to make it a list so its easier to look through because later on in my program since I want to be able to get user input like year and list all the books within the year with. It will also make formating an output easier.

Comment: If you want a list you can use `test_data.split(',')`. Your example output is a dictionary, though, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Could you be more specific with what output you want. A list of dictionaries or a dictionary of lists?

Comment: @pySam1459 im trying to make a dic so its easier to search afterwords because I have upwards of 300 lines of information I'm trying to go throught

Comment: @BTables yes im llooking for a dict as it easier to use afterwards in my program

Comment: Is the order will always remain same?

Comment: @Sabil if i underdstand what your saying yes I would like the order to stay the same if posible

Comment: Take a look at the built-in `csv` module.

Comment: If you can ensure that the string order will be same then we can achieve this else it will not possible to identify which one is name or author and so on

Comment: @sabil yes the order for the information will always be the same and their wont be any part where information is missing

Comment: it looks like CSV file and maybe you should read it with `pandas` and keep it as `DataFrame` instead of `dictionaries`. `DataFrame` has many functions to filter, select, and edit data (without using `for`-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are reading the data from a .txt file

```py
data = {'Name': [], 'Author': [], 'User Rating': [], 'Reviews': [], 'Price': [], 'Publication Year': [], 'Genre': []}

with open("filename/goes/here.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        lineData = line.split(r",")

        for key, ld in zip(data.keys(), lineData):
            data[key].append(ld)
```

From your description I believe this is a solution.
Some advice, never name your variables with the same name as any built-in functions. (e.g. list, int, str)

Comment: Yes, It should be fixable. `with open("filename/goes/here.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: Quick question about the code  if i were to search for a certain name. would I need to get the location of that within the list to get the other info on in like author name and user rating, etc...

Comment: Yes, if you find the index of a certain name in `data['Name']`, then you can use this index to get the rest of the data `data['Author'][32]`, would get the 33rd Author

Comment: @pySam1459 , i guess `readlines` may not work correctly all the time. As one text might get cut if its too big.

Comment: you can read the whole file once and the split it using `.split(",")` attribute. Rest all code is perfect. :)

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirement

> I'm trying to make it a list so its easier to look through because later on in my program since I want to be able to get user input like year and list all the books within the year with. It will also make formating an output easier.

I think that a list of dictionaries would do the job. Using list comprehension (I am using the *test_data* you defined in the question):

```
tags = ["Name", "Author", "User Rating", "Reviews", "Price", "Publication Year", "Genre"]
result = [dict(zip(tags, x.split(","))) for x in test_data.split("\n") if len(x.strip()) > 0]
```

Comment: thanks for the answer this one also worked